# Картинка из интернета Picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

У меня есть ссылка картинки и ее нужно отобразить в `ImageView`. Но она не отображается.

Использую `Picasso`.
Возможно из за ссылки

[Вот ссылка](http://dummyimage.com/189x249.png/5fa2dd/ffffff)

Попробовал другие ссылки, работает. Как такие ссылки отобразить?

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(listData.getPhoto())
            .into(holder.img);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой белый фон и все

Comment: пробовали использовать другую ссылку на картинку?

Comment: попробуйте просто прописать
`Picasso.with(context)
            .load(http://dummyimage.com/189x249.png/5fa2dd/ffffff)
            .into(holder.img);`

Результат каков?

Comment: Другие ссылки пробовал, работает.

Comment: YaPV не показыает, белый фон и все

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался. Ошибка была в ссылке картинки, а точнее вот так: http://dummyimage.com/189x249.png/5fa2dd/ffffff - этот ссылка не отображется
https://dummyimage.com/189x249.png/5fa2dd/ffffff - а вот так работает.
Picasso работает на ура. Спасибо всем